# Is it possible to develop for Windows Azure from another OS?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, deployment, azure

Is it possible to develop for Windows Azure using Java from OS X (Eclipse)?

I've installed the Windows Azure Plugin for Eclipse, but it seems the plugin relies on batch files in order to deploy the app to Azure.

If this is possible, are there any guides on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The development tools, including the Compute and Storage emulators and the packager, require Windows.

For the applications themselves, the requirement is being compatible with Windows Server 2008 R2. So it is possible, for instance, to develop an application on Linux or OS X without using the Azure SDK or tools, and to prepare a virtual image of a Windows Server with a Java application server and a pre-deployed and pre-configured application, and to deploy this image as a [Virtual Machine Role](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg502178). The application could access Windows Azure services via HTTP or by using the Java libraries included as source code in the [SDK](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-java).

This approach would be a better fit for porting existing applications, though. For developing new ones, the tooling available on Windows would make for an improved experience.

Answer (score 2):

The tools required to build the Windows Azure service package only run on Windows. So, while you can easily build Java apps in Eclipse on Windows, you cannot do the same with OSX.

If you're developing with node.js, you can develop using the Cloud9 IDE, which is browser-based and cross-platform. See [this MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/01/24/windows-azure-and-cloud9-ide-at-node-summit.aspx) for more details around this, as Scott Guthrie demonstrated this at the Node Summit in San Francisco in January, doing all coding and deployment via a Mac.